# No parameterless constructor defined in Uno Platform application

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

I am getting a "No parameterless constructor defined" in the recent WASM application I am doing with Uno. Any ideas what might be causing it or how to work around it?

PG

Comment: What's the code that is giving you this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the linker so the types you are manipulating can be used properly. In particular, if there is reflection done on specific types, you'll get this type of error because the linker will remove the code it determines is not used.

For instance, you can edit the `LinkerConfig.xml` file, and add something like this:

```xml
  <assembly fullname="MyAssembly">
    <type fullname="MyNamespace*" />
  </assembly>
```

You can also disable the linker completely to validate if the linker is the source of your issue by adding this to your csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <WasmShellILLinkerEnabled>false</WasmShellILLinkerEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Some additional information can be found [here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/using-il-linker-webassembly.html).